# Собрать данные из двух таблиц mysql

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Есть две таблицы.
Первая таблица студентов с личными данными. Вторая таблица с оплатами. Оплат есть несколько по каждому студенту.

**Задача:** *Вывести всех студентов(из таблицы с личными данными) и инфо(из таблицы с оплатами) по внесенным каждым оплаты.
Необходимо собрать данные из двух таблиц.*

```
таблица с данными:
students
| id_stud | fio     |
|       1 | Ivaov   |
|       2 | Petrov  |
|       3 | Sidorov |

таблица с оплатами:
payments
| id_payment | id_student | amount |
|          1 |          1 |     20 |
|          2 |          1 |     30 |
|          3 |          2 |     10 |
|          4 |          2 |     10 |
|          5 |          3 |     40 |

Ожидаемый результат:

1| Ivaov   | 20 |
           | 30 |

2| Petrov  | 10 |
           | 10 |

3| Sidorov | 40 |
```

Делаю так:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Is</th>
    <th>Fio</th>
    <th>Pago</th>
 </tr>
<?php
  $result = mysql_query(" SELECT * FROM students
  INNER JOIN payment ON students.id_stud = payment.id_student");
  $myrow = mysql_fetch_array($result);
  do{
    print"<tr>
          <td> $myrow[id_stud]</td>
          <td> $myrow[fio]</td>
          <td> $myrow[amount] </td>
          </tr>";                       
                    }
while($myrow = mysql_fetch_array($result));                 
?>
</table>
```

Но выводит каждого студента столько раз сколько было оплат в таблице payments.
Помогите разобраться.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: запоминайте какого студента вы выводили на предыдущей итерации цикла и не отображайте его если совпадает с предыдущим значением

Answer (score 1):

Примерный вариант:

```
 <?php
    //выборка из базы данных
    $list = array();

    $result = query("SELECT id_stud, fio, FROM students");

    while($data = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){ 

        $result2 = query("SELECT id_payment, amount FROM payments WHERE id=".$data['id_stud']);
        $list2=array();
        if($data['id_stud']!=NULL){
        while($pay = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result2)){ 
            $list2[]=array(
                  'id_payment'=>$pay['id_payment'],
                  'amount'=>$pay['amount'],
              );
        }
       }

        $list[]=array(
            'id_stud'=>$data['id_stud'],
            'fio'=>$data['fio'],
            'pay'=>$list2
        );

    }

    //перебор массива и вывод данных.
    foreach ($list as $key => $row) {
        echo  $row['id_stud'];
        echo $row['fio'];
        foreach ($list2 as $key_m => $col) {
            echo $row['pay'][$key_m]['id_payment'];
            echo $row['pay'][$key_m]['amount'];
        }
    }
    ?>
```

Comment: Делаю как написал Николай Габараев. Выдает ошибку: Fatal error: Call to undefined function query() in...

Comment: Пробовал менять query() на mysqli_query() выдает такие ошибки: Warning: mysqli_query() expects at least 2 parameters, 1 given in Z:\home\localhost\www\AdminLTE\pages\magdalena\students_view_test.php on line 93

Warning: mysqli_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, null given in Z:\home\localhost\www\AdminLTE\pages\magdalena\students_view_test.php on line 95

Comment: ой. прошу прощения. `query` - это функция.
Она получает параметры запроса и соединяется с базой  через `mysqli_query`
Вам надо написать код, где вы подключаетесь к базе, например `$link = mysqli_connect("111.111.11.11", "user", "pass")` и функцию 
`function query($query){ global $link;    
    if($response=mysqli_query($link, $query)){
        return $response;
    }
    return false; 
}`

Comment: к слову, этот же цикл может сформировать вашу таблицу.

Answer (score 1):

Вариант 1. Запрос изменить немного, используя `GROUP_CONCAT(payments.sample_number) AS amounts`. В итоге в каждой строке будет что-то такое `1| Ivaov | 20, 30` - все amount будут объединены через запятую, а если только один amount, то запятой ну будет. На стороне php потом можно сделать `explode()` по запятой.

Замечу, что если у студента нет оплат, то ваш запрос пропустит такого студента, т.к. для него не будет записей в таблице оплат. Чтобы исправить, нужно использовать `RIGHT OUTER JOIN`.

Вариант 2. Делать if и т.п., как советуют в комментарии.

Вариант 3. Делать перебор всех полученных значений из БД, собирая новый многомерный массив - такой, как нужно. Примерно вот так (но лучше тогда собирать все это на стороне sql - смотри первый вариант) и сразу выводить

```
$new_arr = [];
while($myrow = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    $id_stud = $myrow['id_stud'];
    $new_arr[$id_stud]['name'] = $myrow['fio'];
    $new_arr[$id_stud]['payments'][] = $myrow['amount'];
}
print_r($new_arr);
```

Вывести в таблицу можно примерно вот так. `printf` использовать не обязательно. выводите хоть с `echo`. А `implode()` объединяет все элементы массива через запятую в одну строку.

```
foreach($new_arr as $key => $value ) {
    printf("
        <tr>
            <th>%s</th>
            <th>%s</th>
            <th>%s</th>
         </tr>
    ", 
        $value['id_stud'],
        $value['name'],
        implode($value['payments'], ', ')
    );

}
```

через echo

```
foreach($new_arr as $key => $value ) {
    echo "
        <tr>
            <th>$value['id_stud']</th>
            <th>$value['name']</th>
            <th>implode($value['payments'], ",\n")</th>
         </tr>
    ";
}
```

Comment: n.osennij, Подскажите как вывести данные в таблицу из этого масива: $new_arr ?

Comment: @Balamoot а вам нужна именно такая структура таблицы?

Comment: n.osennij, Да. У меня есть таблица с основными данными по студенту (students). и таблица где лежат данные с оплатами (payments).

Comment: n.osennij, Да. У меня есть таблица с основными данными по студенту (students), и таблица где лежат данные с оплатами (payments). Хочу вывести список студентов со всеми оплатами по каждому. Делаю как вы написали, только исправил $new_arr = []; на $new_arr = array();  И через команду: print_r($new_arr); и получаю многомерный массив вида: Array ( [1] => Array ( [fio] =>Gomez [payments]=>Array ( [0] =>220 [1] => 200 [2] => 297 ) ) [2] =>Array ( [fio] =>Cristina[payments]=>Array ( [0] => 0 [1] => 220 [2] => 210 ) ) ) Вроде все как нужно.Помогите перебрать его ч/з foreach и вывести все в таблицу.

Comment: @Balamoot Так я и спрашиваю - выводить вам точно нужно в такую таблицу, как вы в вопросе указали (просто это не очень удобно). Или же это не сильно важно? В смысле, обязательно ли для каждой оплаты студента делать новую строку?

Comment: n.osennij, А да точно сорри, забыл сказать. Дело в том что у 90% студентов будет 3 оплаты. Курс делится натри платежа. Но иногда есть студенты которые платят: по месячно, в два платежа или в четыре платежа, но таких мало. Поэтому хотелось когда смотришь на общий список студентов видеть какой вид платежа у данного студента, даты планируемых оплат(это видно из таблицы students), и сколько уже сделано платежей. Или вы можете посоветовать более удобный вид?

Comment: Потом планирую вывести в отдельном файле список всех должников. Но пока думаю выводить так как написал, тоесть основная таблица, а внутри каждого студента в ячейке оплат своя табличка с оплатами.

Comment: @Balamoot вы меня слишком грузите. Вам мой код подходит или нет? Можно сделать так, чтобы оплаты были построчно - `implode($value['payments'], ",\n")`

Comment: @n-osennij, извините за то что гружу вас. Да код отлично работает!!!! Спасибо большое!!! Но можете показать как вывести это ч/з echo.  echo $new_arr = $value['id_stud']; echo $new_arr = $value['fio']; ... ? Как вывести все оплаты для каждого студента в виде таблицы. Спасибо еще раз!

Comment: @Balamoot я уже вообще не понимаю в чём дело и в чём сложность. Обновил код.

Comment: @n-osennij, спасибо за вашу помощь. Все вроде работает как надо. Спасибо и другим участникам, которые помогали разобрать данный вопрос. Спасибо ресурсу stackoverflow.